# jquery $(document).on("scroll") disable

Tags: jquery, sticky, onscroll

I have build so far a function that stick html element to the top of the page when scrolling but i want to create a function inside this to destroy $(document).on("scroll") for each asigned element. Can someone help me to achive this?
My code so far is:

```
$(element).each(function() {
    var default_settings = {
        parent: null,
        offsetTop: 0,
        offsetBottom: 0,
        fixBottom: true
    };

    var elm = $(this),
        parent = $(settings.parent);

    var elmTop = elm.offset().top,
        elmLeft = elm.offset().left,
        elmWidth = elm.width(),
        elmHeight = elm.height(),
        parentTop = parent.offset().top,
        parentHeight = parent.outerHeight(true),
        offs = elmTop - settings.offsetTop,
        margin_top = elmTop - parentTop,
        margin_bottom = parentHeight - elmHeight - margin_top,
        diff = parentHeight - elmHeight + parentTop - settings.offsetTop - settings.offsetBottom;

    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
       var w_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(w_top > offs && w_top < diff) {
            elm.attr("style", "position: fixed; top: "+settings.offsetTop+"px; left: "+elmLeft+"px; margin-left: 0;");
            if(!elm.next('[data-sticket-controller]').length) {
                elm.after('<div data-sticket-controller style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; position: relative; width: '+elmWidth+'px; height: '+elmHeight+'px;"></div>');
            }
        }
        else if(w_top >= diff) {
            if(settings.fixBottom) {
                elm.attr("style", "position: absolute; bottom: "+settings.offsetBottom+"px; left: "+elmLeft+"px; margin-left: 0;");
            }
        }
        else {
            elm.removeAttr("style");
            elm.next("[data-sticket-controller]").remove();
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want to remove the scroll handler for particular elements?

Comment: yes how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can take the anonymous function you are putting into the scroll binding and put it in a variable.  Then when you want to remove it, you can just do `$(document).off('scroll', THEVARIABLE);`

Comment: but this variable should be different for each element initialized

Comment: Yes, if you define it as a local variable to the each that is looping over the elements, it will be unique per iteration.  Just like `default_settings` is a unique variable per iteration, the same as any variable in your each that begins with `var`

Comment: but how can i recall this?

Comment: What do you mean?  `var something = function() { ... }; $(document).on('scroll', something);` and then later `$(document).off('scroll', something);`

Comment: but this variable should be globaly to call it outside function

Comment: No, because each of your callbacks uses variable specific to the iteration.  It cannot be a shared global method the way you have it written.  Also if they all used the same method, then removing it would remove it for all the elements, which you are saying you don't want.

Comment: yes exactly, but how can i rebuilt it? Can you give me an idea im new in javascript

Comment: What do you mean rebuilt it?

Comment: to designe as a function. To call and to disable later

Comment: I mean, I just told you how to.  If you are asking now how to rewrite the function so it can be shared by all the elements, then your question is staring to become too broad.